# Etymology of 其他

Tags: etymology

In Chinese, one uses the phrase 其他 when refering to other things. In Japanese one uses a similiar phrase: 其の他 (Sono ta), where 其 is often written in Hiragana: その他. Since the meaning is identical, I want to ask whether these two phrases have an etymological connection. If yes, which language's phrase appeared first?

Comment: The most oldest record I can find now is from `国语`. In chapter called `晋语四`, `民生安乐，谁知其他？`. It is considered this book is written in late `春秋` or early `战国` period. Maybe around 5th century B.C.

Comment: 康熙字典：《小雅》人知其一，莫知其他。

Comment: Perhaps more important is that you know the Chinese word 词源 (origin of a word; etymology). By googling "其他的词源" you find the first result (http://cidian.xpcha.com/297628drose.html) contains halfelf's citation above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

其の他 can also be read as "sono hoka" in Japanese, both consisting of native Japanese morphemes. In "sono ta", only the "ta" (他) is borrowed from Chinese. Early citations for both expressions is c. 14th century. Japanese borrowed much vocabulary from Chinese. It is entirely possible that the reading "sono ta" or "sono hoka" developed from the Chinese 其他. However, as halfelf has cited, the Chinese is much older, so Japanese likely did not have any effect on the Chinese expression.

Comment: Hi @Dono, thanks for your answer. It would be helpful if you could provide sources for any claims you make to support your answer.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 The standard reference for early Japanese citations is 日本国語大辞典 (Nihon Kokugo Daijiten), 2nd edition.

Comment: @Dono You can't say "Japanese did not have any effect on the Chinese expression." 经济, 世界语 and so on are come from Japanese.

Comment: @MikeManilone You misquoted me. I suggest that you re-read what I wrote: (for reasons given) "so Japanese LIKELY did not have any effect on THE Chinese expression." THE Chinese expression being referred to here is 其他.

Answer (score -2):

I think 其他 and 其の他 appeared first in Japanese. 其の他 often appeared in 手紙、仕樣書. It means ceremonial and honorific. But in chinese 其他 was used extensively everywhere.

Comment: I don't think so. And this reason is not sufficient enough. In history, Chinese has a great influence on Japanese. But the converse is much less.

Comment: Very unlikely given the citation evidence.

Comment: @Lomography thanks for your answer. It would be helpful if you could provide a source or evidence to support your claim.

Comment: It's more likely that 其の他 arose as a calque of 其他.